# Is there a formula for rotational energy in relativity

Tags: special-relativity, rotational-dynamics

I've been searching for days for a formula that describes the rotational energy of a disk(ideally rigid but not necessary) at relativistic speeds. I know that the classical equation is E = Iw^2 . I cant find a simple equation for this in relativity. Everyone talks about translational kinetic energy but never relativistic rotational energy. Any help will is appreciated